# Firebase not sending email verification when user is registered.

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

Do you guys know what the problems is? I need Firebase to send email verification right when user is registered. Does this logic work and what am I missing if I am? Firebase is registering users very well.

```
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bRegister:
                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(schoolEmail, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    //save username, state, school
                                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                                    user.sendEmailVerification()
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        finish();
                                                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registered Successfully. Check your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VerifyEmail.class));
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });

                                    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                                        finish();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CampusMe.class)); //later change to a page that will let the user know they need to verify email.
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Could not Register User. Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                break;
```

Comment: Could you check the value of user.emailVerified? And also look at your junk mail box, because very often the emails sent by firebase fall into junk box.

Comment: Nope they do not get sent to spam or junk mail... I also am using a test phone with no service but I am connected with wifi. However I do not see that as a problem because ti is registering users. I tried to update the:'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1' to 9.8.0 and it would give me errors when I sync

Comment: Also I did receive an email before but I kept deleting myself off firebase Auth list and the emails stopped... I tested with other emails and it did not send.